# How to get the physical name of the fields in a table (db2 database)

Tags: database, db2

Query to fetch the physical name of the field in a table ( database db2)

Comment: What's the Db2 platform and version?

Comment: and what is your question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There are no "fields" in tables.

Comment: "SELECT SYSTEM_COLUMN_NAME FROM [QSYS2.SYSCOLUMNS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=views-syscolumns) WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '...' AND TABLE_NAME = '...'", if it's Db2 for IBM i.

Answer (score 0):

Try "Select * from syscat.columns where tabname='table name' and tabschema='table schema'"